# Twitter Bootstrap fixed navbar transparent in chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, navbar, twitter-bootstrap-2

I've encountered most strange issue, and i can't seem to find anyone else that have encountered it.

I'm doing a site using Bootstrap 2.3.2, have a fixed top navbar that is suppose too have a white background. In safari, Explorer and Firefox it works flawlessly, however in newest Chrome, the navbar is completely transparent when scrolling down?

When scrolled to the top:
[image]

When scrolling down:
[image]

I haven't set "transparent" anywhere, my initial thoughts were along the line that z-index was incorrect or similar but why would it still be on top and transparent? (Also working in all other browsers as it should)

Another clue: there seem to be some flaw to the rendering with this particular setup, since in Chrome when scroll by a embedded Vimeo-video, the menu bar is seen in white over the embedded video.

HTML code as per below:

```
<nav>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>
                 <a class="logo pull-left" href="#home"><img src="img/styleio.png" alt="Styleio"></a>
                <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav pull-right">
                        <li><a class="top-menu" href="#home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a class="top-menu" href="#about">About</a></li>
                        <li><a class="top-menu" href="#offerings">Offerings</a></li>
                        <li><a class="top-menu" href="#features">Features</a></li>
                        <li><a class="top-menu" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                        <!--<a class="btn btn-primary btn-small red-bg pull right" href="#sign">Sign up</a> -->
                    </ul>

                </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

CSS code for the elements:

```
    .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-inner,
  .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-inner {
    padding: 0px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
  }

.nav .navbar {
    border:none;
    background-color:#ffffff;
}

.nav {
    padding-top:20px;
}

.navbar-fixed-top {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.navbar-inner {
  min-height: 90px;
  background-color:#ffffff;
}

.navbar-inverse .nav > li > a {
    border:none;
    color: #666666;
    font-weight:500;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-inner {
  background: #ffffff;
  filter: unquote("progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false)");

}
```

Comment: Got an example or code anywhere?

Comment: Agreed with the code sample request. That being said, I am inclined to think that the white background is attached to something that is not part of the navbar. Does the white background scroll away, or just disappear immediately?

Comment: It is left at the top as if it was a static menu. I'll edit my question with code example.

Comment: applying some height to navbar should fix it

Comment: The big image is pushed down .. I suspect the background is in fault, not the upper menu. Like, the background-image comes over. Your css/html does not show those parts. Can you provide a link?